# facebook join button

Tags: facebook

i'm doing a mobile web app, is it possible to implements the **join event button** on my site?
I would like to join a facebook event directly from my site. Facebook uses this:

Partecipa

Answer (score 0):

see this link
[facebook api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

according to it we can't create use with api in my site .